# Docker Image Pulling with Custom Tag

Tags: mongodb, docker, tagging, docker-image

I want to pull a docker image with a custom tag; for example, if I wanted a mongo image I would:

`docker search mongo`

Resulting in no tags displayed.Then

`docker pull mongo`

and receive as an output the image "mongo:latest"

I know I can tag it after I get the image, but is there a way to simplify this process and retreive an image like "mongo:1.0" with something to the efect of `docker pull xxx`?

Comment: show your code and errorcode.

Comment: well, I didnot get an error here,I just wanna get a image with a customized tag, I know I can get a image and then tag it like `docker tag mongo:latest mongo:1.0`,how can I get it with one instru

Comment: can't you just do `docker pull mongo:1.0`

Comment: since no official image named "mongo:1.0" in the docker store/hub ,I can't

Answer (score 1):

You can at least look at the [official docker mongo page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) and see the tags there.
For instance, to get the previous before latest:

```
docker pull mongo:3.4.11
```